# To write this Pseudocode with Regex

Tags: terminal, cron, regular-expression, python, make

I am doing a Makefile which I run regularly by Crontab every day at 0230

```
crontab -e; 30 2 * * * /bin/thePseudocode
```

Python-like Pseudocode

```
directories = ["Cardiology", "Rheumatology", "Surgery"]
for directory in directories
   files = directory.files(); % not sure if such a parameter exists
   files = files.match(.*tex); % trying to get only tex files; not sure if match exists
   summaryFile = "";
   for texFile in files
      summaryFile.add( ...
                textFile.match( (?s)\\begin{question}.*?\\end{question} ) ...
      )
      % Solution based on this thread
      % Problem in writing this Regex in Perl http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159307/to-match-only-innermost-environment-by-regex
   end
end

save this `summaryFile` as /Users/Masi/Dropbox/QuestionSummary.tex
```

where `files` is the list of all files in the directory, and `summaryFile` is the file which lists all questions in all tex-files. 
Those files, I want finally compile by **pdflatex** and read each morning by pdf-reader.

Example file which locates in the folder **Rheumatology**

```
\section{Takayasu arteritis}

\begin{question}
{You get a patient. 
What do you notice first in this patient?}
Absence of peripheral pulse.
\end{question}

\begin{question}
{What was the first Takayasu case?}
Young woman in Asia with red vessels in the eye. 
So special eye diagnosis done. 
Affects eye.
\end{question}


Fever of unknown origin can be used when you do not know what is causing the disease. 

% Show cases in MedScape and ask class. 

Aneurysms. 


\subsection{Treatment}

\begin{question}
{What you should always include in Takayasu treatment? 
What are the symptoms?}
Blood pressure.
Aneurysms which will burst without treatment. 
So blood pressure decreasing drugs like beta blockers along in combination with other drugs.
\end{question}

\begin{question}
{When is the checkup of the Takayasu arteritis?} 
Only once per year. 
You could expect every month like normally in this kind of diseases.
But only once per year.
\end{question}
```

where the output should be for all files in the folder

```
\section{Rheumatology}

\begin{question}
{You get a patient. 
What do you notice first in this patient?}
Absence of peripheral pulse.
\end{question}

\begin{question}
{What was the first Takayasu case?}
Young woman in Asia with red vessels in the eye. 
So special eye diagnosis done. 
Affects eye.
\end{question}

\begin{question}
{What you should always include in Takayasu treatment? 
What are the symptoms?}
Blood pressure.
Aneurysms which will burst without treatment. 
So blood pressure decreasing drugs like beta blockers along in combination with other drugs.
\end{question}

\begin{question}
{When is the checkup of the Takayasu arteritis?} 
Only once per year. 
You could expect every month like normally in this kind of diseases.
But only once per year.
\end{question}
```

Makefile

```
all: 
   pdflatex /Users/Masi/Dropbox/QuestionsSummary.tex /Users/Masi/Dropbox/QuestionsSummary.pdf
   pdflatex /Users/Masi/Dropbox/QuestionsSummary.tex /Users/Masi/Dropbox/QuestionsSummary.pdf % to compile a few times to be successful
pdflatex 
% I am not sure if I should have some error management, since often the pdflatex crashes
% So pdflatex is not probably the right tool to go
```

**How can you such a pseudocode in any tools preferred by you?** 
I like Python but would not make all by it.

Comment: Please explain your pseudocode in words as well. Presumably, `files` will be the list of all files in the directory right? What's `masterfile.add`? Ideally, show us an example of your input files and what you want your script to do to them.

Comment: @terdon Thank you for your comment! I changed the masterFile's name to summaryFile to be more descriptive. I mean by masterfile.add to add the output of the function to the end of the masterfile.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So what would the output of this script look like? I understand that you want to extract all `\begin{question}... \end{question}` from all `.tex` files in a given directory and save those in a new file. Is that correct? If you expect the output to be compilable by LaTeX, presumably you also want it to be within `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` tags right?

Comment: @terdon Yes, you are correct. Yes, of course within begin{document}. I will add those things then last. I edited to body to include the expected output too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for something like this (in `bash`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## avoid errors if a directory has no *tex files
shopt -s nullglob

directories=("Cardiology" "Rheumatology" "Surgery");

## Change this to set whichever options you want.
printf "%s\n%s\n" "\documentclass{YOURCLASS}" "\begin{document}"

for directory in ${directories[@]}
do
    ## Reset the counter, avoid empty sections.
    c=0;
    for file in "$directory"/*tex
    do
        let c++
        [ "$c" -eq 1 ] && printf "\n%s\n" "\section{$directory}"
        ## Extract the wanted lines
        perl -lne '$a=1 && print "" if /\\begin{question}/; 
                  print if $a==1;
                  $a=0 if /\\end{question}/;' "$file" 
        echo ""
    done
done
echo "\end{document}"
```

If you run that script from the directory that contains Cardiology etc, it should provide output like this:

Comment: How can you add the PATH to these directories. Those directories for instance locate at */Users/Masi/Dropbox/*. I added a parameter like this **path="/Users/Masi/Dropbox/** and **for file in "$path/$directory"/*tex**. I think something wrong in last line.

Comment: @masi just write `for file in /Users/Masi/Dropbox/"$directory"/*tex`. But it should also have worked with the variable.

Comment: See example output below. Duplicate sections only bug. I think the bug is in this line **[ "$c" -eq 1 ] && printf "\n%s\n" "\section{$directory}"**.

Comment: @Masi yes indeed, sorry, silly mistake on my part. It should work as expected now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This seems to work. I will let you know if I see some bugs.

Comment: There is still one missing thing in this file. To save it to some directory. How can you grap the output and save it there. Something like **cat [this-ouput] > /Users/Masi/Dropbox/day_summary.tex**? But inside the script is the problem because I have forgot which symbol or term I had to use here.

Comment: @Masi just save the script as `foo.sh`, make it executable (`chmod 755 foo.sh`) and run it redirecting its output: `/path/to/foo.sh > /path/to/output.tex`.

Comment: Thank you for the addition! Of course, that in makefile.