# To match only innermost environment by Regex

Tags: regular-expression, perl

I want to match the innermost environment of `begin{question}` and its corresponding `end{question}`.

Example data

```
\section{Takayasu arteritis}

\begin{question}
{You get a patient. 
What do you notice first in this patient?}
Absence of peripheral pulse.
\end{question}

\begin{question}
{What was the first Takayasu case?}
Young woman in Asia with red vessels in the eye. 
So special eye diagnosis done. 
Affects eye.
\end{question}


Fever of unknown origin can be used when you do not know what is causing the disease. 

% Show cases in MedScape and ask class. 

Aneurysms. 


\subsection{Treatment}

\begin{question}
{What you should always include in Takayasu treatment? 
What are the symptoms?}
Blood pressure.
Aneurysms which will burst without treatment. 
So blood pressure decreasing drugs like beta blockers along in combination with other drugs.
\end{question}
```

My expected output is

```
\begin{question}
{You get a patient. 
What do you notice first in this patient?}
Absence of peripheral pulse.
\end{question}
```

or

```
\begin{question}
{What was the first Takayasu case?}
Young woman in Asia with red vessels in the eye. 
So special eye diagnosis done. 
Affects eye.
\end{question}
```

or

```
\begin{question}
{What you should always include in Takayasu treatment? 
What are the symptoms?}
Blood pressure.
Aneurysms which will burst without treatment. 
So blood pressure decreasing drugs like beta blockers along in combination with other drugs.
\end{question}
```

**How can you match only the innermost environment?**

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thank you for your comment! I added the expected output.

Comment: This regex will do the job `(?s)\\begin{question}.*?\\end{question}` but i don't know how to implement it in Perl.

Comment: Here `pcregrep -M '(?s)\\begin{question}.*?\\end{question}' file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
pcregrep -M '\\begin{question}(.|\n)*?\\end{question}'
```

Explanation:

- `pcregrep`: grep with Perl-compatible regular expressions
- `-M`: Allow  patterns  to  match  more than one line
- `(.|\n)*?`: any normal character `.` or new line `\n` matched zero or more times `.`, in non-greedy mode `?`.

Result:

```
\begin{question}
{You get a patient. 
What do you notice first in this patient?}
Absence of peripheral pulse.
\end{question}
\begin{question}
{What was the first Takayasu case?}
Young woman in Asia with red vessels in the eye. 
So special eye diagnosis done. 
Affects eye.
\end{question}
\begin{question}
{What you should always include in Takayasu treatment? 
What are the symptoms?}
Blood pressure.
Aneurysms which will burst without treatment. 
So blood pressure decreasing drugs like beta blockers along in combination with other drugs.
\end{question}
```

Comment: even more simpler `pcregrep -M '\\begin{question}[\S\s]*?\\end{question}' file`

Answer (score 1):

Do you need it to be a pure regex solution, or just perlish?

```
perl -lne 'print if(/^\\begin{question}/ .. /^\\end{question}/)'  file
```