# How to write this pseudocode where condition

Tags: text-processing, scripting, perl, latex

This question is extension of this question about [listing questions of directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159297/to-write-this-pseudocode-with-regex). 
I get a problem that I need to understand the original section of the text.

Current output

[image]

where you see the second question does not make sense. 
It was included in the `subsection` *Takayasu arteritis* in the directory Rheumatology:

```
\subsection{Takayasu arteritis}

\begin{question}
{You get a patient. 
What do you notice first in this patient?}
Absence of peripheral pulse.
\end{question}

Lorem ipsum.    

\begin{question}
{What was the first Takayasu case?}
Young woman in Asia with red vessels in the eye. 
So special eye diagnosis done. 
Affects eye.
\end{question}
```

where the current output is by this excellent [code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159312/16920)

```
\section{Rheumatology}  

\begin{question}
{You get a patient. 
What do you notice first in this patient?}
Absence of peripheral pulse.
\end{question}

\begin{question}
{What was the first Takayasu case?}
Young woman in Asia with red vessels in the eye. 
So special eye diagnosis done. 
Affects eye.
\end{question}
```

but I would like it to be

```
\section{Rheumatology}  

\subsection{Takayasu arteritis}

\begin{question}
{You get a patient. 
What do you notice first in this patient?}
Absence of peripheral pulse.
\end{question}

\begin{question}
{What was the first Takayasu case?}
Young woman in Asia with red vessels in the eye. 
So special eye diagnosis done. 
Affects eye.
\end{question}
```

My proposal is to include subsections if there are questions within the subsection.

**My pseudocode**

```
Look for the environment \begin{question}...\end{question}.
See the subsection of the question (it locates above the question). 
   If there is no subsection, leave blank. 
   If there are many questions within one subsection, put only one subsection.
```

Terdon's code

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## avoid errors if a directory has no *tex files
shopt -s nullglob

directories=("Cardiology" "Rheumatology" "Surgery");

## Change this to set whichever options you want.
printf "%s\n%s\n" "\documentclass{YOURCLASS}" "\begin{document}"

for directory in ${directories[@]}
do
    ## Reset the counter, avoid empty sections.
    c=0;
    for file in "$directory"/*tex
    do
        let c++
        [ "$c" -eq 1 ] && printf "\n%s\n" "\section{$directory}"
        ## Extract the wanted lines
        perl -lne '$a=1 && print "" if /\\begin{question}/; 
                  print if $a==1;
                  $a=0 if /\\end{question}/;' "$file" 
        echo ""
    done
done
echo "\end{document}"
```

where I think the logic of these lines should be changed

```
        ## Extract the wanted lines
        perl -lne '$a=1 && print "" if /\\begin{question}/; 
                  print if $a==1;
                  $a=0 if /\\end{question}/;' "$file" 
        echo ""
```

which uses a regex to find all questions in a file, AND ignores the subsections of the questions.

**Example of data** (little different from the last case!)

```
\subsection{Takayasu arteritis}

\begin{question}
{You get a patient. 
What do you notice first in this patient?}
Absence of peripheral pulse.
\end{question}

\begin{question}
{What was the first Takayasu case?}
Young woman in Asia with red vessels in the eye. 
So special eye diagnosis done. 
Affects eye.
\end{question}


Fever of unknown origin can be used when you do not know what is causing the disease. 

% Show cases in MedScape and ask class. 

Aneurysms. 


\subsubsection{Treatment}

\begin{question}
{What you should always include in Takayasu treatment? 
What are the symptoms?}
Blood pressure.
Aneurysms which will burst without treatment. 
So blood pressure decreasing drugs like beta blockers along in combination with other drugs.
\end{question}

\begin{question}
{When is the checkup of the Takayasu arteritis?} 
Only once per year. 
You could expect every month like normally in this kind of diseases.
But only once per year.
\end{question}
```

where you can ignore subsubsections in the application.

**How can you write the pseudocode?**

---

### **Bug in Terdon's code 14.10.2014 found**

Example of data which causes the bug

```
\subsection{3}
A 55 y.o male says that for the last year ... 

\begin{question}
{What is the pathogenetic mechanism of his complains?} 
\end{question}
```

which parsed by Terdon's code gives exactly the same result which is wrong, since the sentence *A 55 y.o...* should not be there anymore in the final result.
If there is a enter between the subsection and the body text, then correct output. 
However, this cannot be assumed.

The cause of this bug is the Windows symbols, moved [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165336/16920).

Comment: "Pseudocode" makes this a general programming question. →[SO](http://stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: @Anko no, this is basically a text parsing question and those are on topic here.

Comment: It should be in shell script?

Comment: 'Extract and merge sections from Q&As in all .tex files for specific directories: the case of "subsubsections"?'. Not certain if this is an accurate title as the "section" aspect of the 2 questions and the interplay is hard to grasp, in my opinion. It is about the hierarchy of the question components in the .tex files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to extend my original code but it is getting to a point where it's much easier to just reimplement everything in Perl directly:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

## This is the path to the target  directories
my $path="/Users/Masi/Dropbox/";

## The target directories
my @directories=("Cardiology","Rheumatology","Surgery");

## Iterate over the directories
foreach my $dir (@directories) {
    my $dd=0;
    ## Read the current directory
    opendir (my $DIR, "$path/$dir");
    ## Find all files in this directory
    while (my $file = readdir($DIR)) {
        ## Reset the counter
        my $c=0;
        ## Skip any files that aren't .tex
        next unless $file =~ /\.tex$/;

        ## Open the file
        open(my $fh,"$path/$dir/$file");

        while (<$fh>) {
            ## Get the subsection. $_ is the current line.
            $sub="$_" and $n=0 if /\\subsection{/;
            ## If this line is a question
            if (/\\begin{question}/) {
                ## If this counter is 0, this is the first file
                ## of this directory, so print the section
                ## Print the section name
                if ($dd==0) {
                    print "\\section{$dir}\n\n";
                    $dd++;
                } 
                ## If this counter is 0, this is the first question
                ## of this subsection, so print the subsection line
                print "$sub\n" if $n==0;

                $n++;
                ## Increment the counter, we want these lines
                $c++;
                ## And print
                print;
            }
            else {
                ## Print lines if the counter is 1
                print if $c==1;
                ## reset the counter to 0
                print "\n" and $c=0 if /\\end{question}/;
            }
        }
        print "\n";
    }

}
```

Note that this ignores subsubsections but it would be easy to modify it to include them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I run this like this **perl /Users/Masi/Dropbox/makeSummary.pl**. I get no output. What is the expected output? I changed the parameter path to **/Users/Masi/Dropbox/**. Some subtle bug somewhere.

Comment: Is there something wrong here **if (/\\begin{question}/) { ... print; }**. In the subsection and matching question environment, it says **print**. Is that enough for printing the content of the of the question?

Comment: @Masi not sure what you mean. Doesn't it produce the output you wanted? In perl, `print` with no arguments will print the current value of the special variable `$_`. In this context, that is the current line of the input file. So, `if` block will print the `\begin{question}` line and also increment `$c`. The `else` block will print the current line if `$c==1`. The result is that the entire question should be printed.

Comment: It returns nothing as the output. What do you get as an output?

Comment: @Masi I get precisely what you show in your question. Are you sure the directories are under `/Users/Masi/Dropbox/`? The script expects to find, for example,`/Users/Masi/Dropbox/Rheumatology/file.tex`.

Comment: My Perl version is **This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 2 (v5.16.2)**. What is your version?

Comment: @Masi the version shouldn't make any difference. If you have no output, its because its not finding any files. Ping me (@terdon) in [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17654/room-for-terdon-and-masi) if you like and I can try and debug it for you.

Comment: See below extension or improvement to your code. I added some error management. Next step is to get this more object-oriented. :)

Comment: I found one bug in the code: see my update of the body. I will be in our chat room. The same bug occurs also in my code below.

Comment: @Masi I can't reproduce it and I also would like to point out that this is a Q&A site, not a script writing service. I'm happy to help out with a _specific_ problem but less happy to provide support and upgrades for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! That is strange. Did you have such piece of data as I indicated in your data? I will try to get RegexBuddy to work in Windows to test this more.

Comment: I found the source of the bug! It is because there are some Windows marks in my data. I opened a new thread about it here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165336/16920

Answer (score 1):

**Extension or improvement of terdon's code** based on the some logic in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159689/16920)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

## This is the path to the target  directories
my $path="/Users/Masi/Dropbox/";
chdir $path or die "cannot chdir '$path'";

## Iterate over the directories
foreach my $dir (
    "Cardiology", "Pathophysiology", "Patology and Biopsy", "Physiology",
    "Propedeutics", "Radiology", "Rheumatology", "Surgery"
)
{
    my $dd=0;
    ## Read the current directory
    opendir my $DIR, $dir or die "cannot opendir '$dir'";

    ## Find all files in this directory
    while (my $file = readdir($DIR)) {
        ## Reset the counter
        my $c=0;
        ## Skip any files that aren't .tex
        next unless $file =~ /\.tex$/;

        ## Open the file
        open(my $fh,"$path/$dir/$file");

        while (<$fh>) {
            ## Get the subsection. $_ is the current line.
            $sub="$_" and $n=0 if /\\subsection{/;
            ## If this line is a question
            if (/\\begin{question}/) {
                ## If this counter is 0, this is the first file
                ## of this directory, so print the section
                ## Print the section name
                if ($dd==0) {
                    print "\\section{$dir}\n\n";
                    $dd++;
                }
                ## If this counter is 0, this is the first question
                ## of this subsection, so print the subsection line
                print "$sub\n" if $n==0;

                $n++;
                ## Increment the counter, we want these lines
                $c++;
                ## And print
                print;
            }
            else {
                ## Print lines if the counter is 1
                print if $c==1;
                ## reset the counter to 0
                print "\n" and $c=0 if /\\end{question}/;
            }
        }
        print "\n";
    }
    closedir $DIR  or die "cannot closedir '$dir'";
}
```

where I added some error management.