# Neutralisation of data from Windows to Unix

Tags: scripting, perl, newlines

I just noticed that other platforms files (Windows) had to cause me many bugs, like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159469/16920), in my regexes. 
Mostly, the line ending `^M`.

There seems to be many ways to do dos2unix, like [here](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/convert_the_line_endings_in_a_text_file_from_dos_to_unix_format.html) described.
However, I am not sure if this is enough for the character `^M` problem i.e. from all Windows systems to Unix.

Exmple code

```
while (my $file = readdir($DIR)) {
    ## Reset the counter
    my $c=0;
    ## Skip any files that aren't .tex
    next unless $file =~ /\.tex$/;

    ## Open the file
    open(my $fh,"$path/$dir/$file");
    ######### TODO  I think the replacement should be done here
    ######### Pseudocode : 's/\r\n/\n/' input.txt

    while (<$fh>) {...}

        s/\r\n\z//;  # TODO bug here, 
                     # This line is not affecting the file globally. 
                     # I need to somehow apply the replament to the file. 
                     # Probably, I should do it globally, since this seems to be only locally. 
                     # What do you think?
```

which returns data like this in my unix system

> \subsection{3}^MA 45 y.o male says that for the last year he
>   occasionally has regurgitated  particles from food eaten several days
>   earlier.

**What is the difference between the following replacements?**

### [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15735143/54964)

```
s/\r\n\z//;
```

which is returning no apparent replacements at all.

### #2

```
s/\r\n\z//g;
```

which is not returning correct data. 
The above data *{3}^MA 4* can be still seen in the output.

### [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/882136/54964)

```
s/\R//g;
```

which returns falsely oriented data like

```
\subsection{4}All the following are associated with an increased risk for gallstones, except:
\begin{question}{Why hemolysis can give gall stones?}Bilirubin accumulation.\end{question}
...
\begin{question}{Vomiting. Why?}Neuropathy of stomach. Changes in the nervous system of the intestinal system. Not using insulin all the time. % Ketone irritation possible. % ketoacidosis \end{question}
```

where everything is put into one line even comments, so not #2.

**What is appropriate way of doing win2unix in Perl scripting?**

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732552/how-to-remove-cr-lf-end-of-line-in-perl

Comment: Why don't you use a readily made tool? Like `tofrodos`?

Comment: @SiyuanRen You are right! I am trying to use now this command in OSX Yosemite. I made your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

good answer is in Siyuan Ren's comment. Use somehow the command

```
tofrodos
```

Comment: My attempt to use this command in OSX Yosemite here http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/177697/15504